# String Date + Time to Date Object Java

Tags: java, date, time, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a `string "8/2/2018 04:25 AM"` into a `date object` but it seems to be converting it wrong making it output a completely wrong `date` and `time` when I do a `date.toString()`. Note - I do not care about the `date.toString()` format, I just need it to be the same date and time

Here is my code,

```
String timestampString = dateText.getText().toString() + " " + timeText.getText().toString();
try {
     Date timestamp2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a").parse(timestampString);
     Log.d("TIME", timestamp2.toString());

} catch (ParseException e) {Log.d("TAG", e)}
```

Here is the output:

```
D/TIME: Wed Feb 07 23:25:00 EST 2018
```

if anyone could lead me in the right direction, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Timezone issue. Set SimpleDateFormat or the Date or both to the correct timezone to fix.

Comment: How do I go about doing that ?

Comment: Search before posting. This has been addressed many many many times already. And never use `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Use only *java.time* classes instead.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right log entry? I am wondering whether you copied the log entry and added it here without changing it? Because colon is present at the end and d/ is present at the beginning.

Comment: @notionquest It looks like the right date-time, only 5 hours off, which would typically be a time zone issue.

Comment: As an aside and assuming you’re programming for Android, consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my Java 9. When I set my time zone to America/New_York, I get `D/TIME: Thu Feb 08 04:25:00 EST 2018`. It would appear that your formatter uses UTC, but I would have expected both it and `Date.toString()` to use the same time zone, namely the time zone setting of your JVM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simpledateformat changing timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112775/simpledateformat-changing-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/uuuu");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateText.getText(), dateFormatter);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeText.getText(), timeFormatter);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(time);
    Log.d("TIME", dateTime.toString());
```

Prints:

> D/TIME: 2018-02-08T04:25

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.The `Date` class that you were using is long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` is too and also notoriously troublesome. Avoid those if you can. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with. And offers the `LocalXx` classes that don’t have time zones, which guarantees to guard you against time zone issues. That said, you may want to convert your date-time into a `ZonedDateTime` in a time zone of your choice to make it an unambiguous point in time.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.